# Doctrine 2 PreInsert equivalent?

Tags: events, doctrine-orm, listener

I understand there is no PreInsert listener in Doctrine2, right?
Is the equivalnet PrePersist? And if so, how do I check if the object is being inserted or updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all intents and purposes PrePersist is PreInsert. it will not be called for entities that are only updated - you can use PreUpdate for that.

Here are the relevant docs: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/events.html#prepersist

Comment: Keep in mind guys, that prePersist event is triggering when you call $this->persist($entity), but preUpdate when $this->flush()