# Default value for foreign key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, entity, foreign-key-relationship

**Context** :
I develop an Rest API with symfony2. I use Doctrine, FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle.
I configure my entities with annotations. I generated my entities with console.

I have two entities : `User` and `Plan`.
`User` extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User of FOSUserBundle.
These two entities are linked by a bidirectional `ManyToOne` relation (Lot of users for one plan).
So i have a foreign key `plan_id` of type int(11) in `user` table in my database.
Here is the code of my entities :

**Plan** :

```
class Plan implements PlanInterface
{
    /* ... */

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="...\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="plan")
    */
    private $users;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**User** :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /* ... */

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\PlanBundle\Entity\Plan", inversedBy="users")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(columnDefinition="INT(11) default '1'")
    */
    private $plan;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**Problem** :
I will wish put a default value (an int of value 1, who represent the first entry of the table `plan`) in the column `plan_id` of the table `user` when i create a new user.

I hope I was clear,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible with annotation. You should probably just have the logic for the user creation in a separate service, which would include adding this default plan to the user. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841925/how-to-set-default-value-of-association)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 PreInsert equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719368/doctrine-2-preinsert-equivalent)

Comment: @Peter I don't know how do it, it doesn't work when i try.

Comment: @ChadSikorra I tried and it works well. But i would put plan_id to 1 also when i create user by console or all others way when i don't use my controller.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use an event subscriber.

As soon as you call `$em->persist($user)` the listener will be called and you can perform any action you wish.

```
class DefaultPlanSubscriber implements \Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postPersist'
        );
    }

    public function postPersist(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em   = $args->getEntityManager();
        $user = $args->getEntity();

        if (false === $user instanceof \MyBundle\Entity\User) {
            return;
        }

        // Select plan by ID or some other sophisticated method of determining default.
        if(null === $plan = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Plan')->find(1)) {
            return;
        }

        $user->setPlan($plan->addUser($user));
    }
}
```